# What's this piece under the nut on my faucet, and could it be stopping me from loosening the nut?

Tags: faucet

I'm trying to remove my kitchen faucet, and have not been able to get this nut to budge with any of locking pliers, pb blaster penetrating oil, and a basin wrench. After looking more closely at it, I noticed this "sleeve" or cover of the threads of the screw the nut is on, which is different from what I've seen in the guides I've been referencing.

I'm wondering what this piece is and if it may be preventing me from loosening the nut.

[image: Photo of underside of faucet attachment]

Comment: What ever it is, it looks like it has notches on either side for a flat blade screwdriver to engage and remove it. It will take a large one to catch both notches simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

That piece is a threaded sleeve nut that is actually holding the faucet in place. the nut at the top just holds the bracket in place while the sleeve nut is tightened or loosened with a large slotted screwdriver. Support the bracket with an adjustable wrench while turning the sleeve nut counterclockwise with slotted screwdriver to remove the faucet.